# How to extract span text value in this case for CSS selector?

Tags: css, beautifulsoup, scrapy, css-selectors

```
<p>
  <span class="name">type:</span> phone
  <span class="name">comment</span>
  : there are 103002 units
</p>
```

I want to extract the values of 'phone' and 'there are 103002'. I can get the  type and comment:

```
response.css('p span.name').getall()
```

But how to extract 'phone' and 'there are 103002 units' with the corresponding keys (type & comment)?

Comment: Why don't you put them also in a `<span>`.

Comment: What do you mean? @ManasKhandelwal I can't change the source html.

Comment: How close does (just off the top of my head) - something like: `.css('p span.name').xpath('normalize-space(./following::text()[1])')` get you ?

Comment: @JonClements This seems working.

Comment: without knowing if there's multiple `<p>` tags that may contain more than just two fixed order items etc... it's hard to tell...

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by xPath:

```java
response.selector.xpath('//p/text()').getall()
```

or this:

```java
response.css('p::text').getall()
```

Check more in here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#constructing-selectors

Comment: How do you pair it with the key?

Comment: Maybe you can pair it by the index?

Comment: What's the normal way to extract such pairs from html? Is this common?

Comment: For this HTML , I think it can only be extract like this.

Answer (score 0):

With BeautifulSoup, you can use the [`.next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) method

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<p>
  <span class="name">type:</span> phone
  <span class="name">comment</span>: there are 103002 units
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all("span", class_="name"):
    print(tag.text, tag.next_sibling.strip())
```

Output:

```
type: phone
comment : there are 103002 units
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following `reduce`, `call` function on this site: [get element’s text content without its child nodes](https://medium.com/@roxeteer/javascript-one-liner-to-get-elements-text-content-without-its-child-nodes-8e59269d1e71), paired with other logic to get the key and values into an array matched as key/value pairs. I recommend reading the article in full as it explains all the steps for getting the textNodes using reduce and call methods in full detail. The method runs over the nodeList and checks the childs `nodeType`, this builds the **textContent** by adding matches to the result.

We can check `nodeType`: `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` => **value** === `1` for the keys... Example: *An Element node like `<p>` or `<div>`*.

Then we check `nodeType`: `Node.TEXT_NODE` => **value** === `3` for the text... Example: *The actual Text inside an Element or Attr.*

See the following article on MDN: [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

We add the return value to a variable. Optionally, you can split the string at the colon to separate the results, then trim the results to get the text content.

To pair the *key* and *value* we create an **object**, then iterate over the ***keys*** or ***value*** *split()* array with a *for* loop using an incrementor and *arr.length*, add the **key/value** pairs to the **object**. A ***for of*** loop to get the **key/value** pairs.

```js
const parentElement = document.querySelector('p');

const keyValuePairs = (el) => {
  let text = [].reduce.call(el.childNodes, (a, b) => {
    return a + (b.nodeType === 3 ? b.textContent : '');
  }, '');
  let keys = [].reduce.call(el.childNodes, (a, b) => {
    return a + (b.nodeType === 1 ? b.textContent : '');
  }, '');
  let arrValues = text.split(':');
  let arrKeys = keys.split(':');
  let obj = {};
  // Using loop to insert key/value pairs into the Object 
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
    obj[arrKeys[i]] = arrValues[i];
  }
  return obj;
}

// Iterate over the object and get the key/value pairs
for (let key of Object.keys(keyValuePairs(parentElement))) {
  if (keyValuePairs(parentElement)[key] !== undefined) {
    console.log(`${key.trim()} => ${keyValuePairs(parentElement)[key].trim()}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="name">type:</span> phone
  <span class="name">comment</span>: there are 103002 units
</p>
```